# Python scripting for using forms

Tags: python-2.7

I need to create groups on a server instance from its frontend. I need to do the following:

1. Login to the server
2. Check if the requested group already exists.
3. If it doesnot, then create a new group. For this I need to fill a form. group name will be provided by the requestor, the rest of the things will be selected from drop-down menu and all of them have a default value.

All this has to be done using python. I know how to connect to a server frontend. but i am not sure about checking the existence of the group name and how to select options from a drop-down

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a database and store group names and when a user want to create a new group take the group and query the database if a group with that name already exist if yes send a message to the user that the group already exist else add new group and continue with other options,I don't know if this is what you want